# WPF Databinding: How do I access the "parent" data context?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have a list (see below) contained in a window. The window's `DataContext` has two properties, `Items` and `AllowItemCommand`.

How do I get the binding for the `Hyperlink`'s `Command` property needs to resolve against the window's `DataContext`?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Action">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock>

                <!-- this binding is not working -->
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding AllowItemCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Allow" />
                </Hyperlink>

              </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you get into the debugger and step through to the point where the UI is being built? If so can you get into the variable and try to drill up

Comment: Simple solution (which also works in Windows 8 Store/Metro app) is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366609/how-to-access-parents-datacontext-in-window-8-store-apps/15419382#15419382](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366609/how-to-access-parents-datacontext-in-window-8-store-apps/15419382#15419382)

Answer (score 466, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
...Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.AllowItemCommand}" ...
```

Comment: I used this to bind to a ICommand on my VM from a ContextMenu set on a ListBoxItem from within a Style.  Worked great, thanks!!

Comment: How does one do this in a Windows 8 app? I used "ElementName=..." to get it to work, but it leaks the DataContext

Comment: Sadly didn't work for me because the parent is in a different file.

Comment: @Thomas6767 , Hope you have solved your issue can your please your code.

Comment: @MohdAbrarAhmed Could take a while, but I'll dig it up this weekend.

Comment: Thanks!  I was confusing myself with a relative binding because I was thinking it would give me the DataContext of the ancestor, not the ancestor itself.  Adding the DataContext.<MyProperty> solved the problem :)

Answer (score 54):

This will also work:

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},
                             Path=DataContext.AllowItemCommand}" />
```

`ListView` will inherit its `DataContext` from `Window`, so it's available at this point, too.
And since `ListView`, just like similar controls (e. g. `Gridview`, `ListBox`, etc.), is a subclass of `ItemsControl`, the `Binding` for such controls will work perfectly.

Comment: (Looking at the poster and the editor) I find this post funny... :D

Comment: @JackFrost if Yoda interferes with Kylo'l work again. Kylo is going to kill Yoda. :P

Comment: Nope, he can't. Yoda is one with the force now. Hehehe

Answer (score 10):

This also works in Silverlight 5 (perhaps earlier as well but i haven't tested it). I used the relative source like this and it worked fine.

`RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}"`