# How to access DataContext of parent in wpf when parent type can be different?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I need to access DataContext of parent in wpf xaml. The whole xaml page code is dynamic. So don't know about the type of parent.

I am writing this

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding Path=.}>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Try it - if its work its correct

Comment: Possible duplicate: [WPF Databinding: How do I access the “parent” data context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127933/wpf-databinding-how-do-i-access-the-parent-data-context)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that if `DataContext` is not explicitly set, it will inherit its parent's `DataContext`. If, for some reason, this doesn't work, you should take a look at binding with [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx).

Something like this might work:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext}}"
```

Given that the `Grid` has an ancestor of type `Window` (which I think all controls should have).

Comment: Thanks. By default it works. Just want to know for knowledge if the AncestorType is not Window for the parent and I set Binding as you mentioned, then what will happen?

Comment: If you specify `AncestorType` of `Window` and the element has no ancestors of type `Window` (which I guess will never happen) the binding will simply not work. This is the same behavior you get when binding to a `Path` which does not exist. Again, read the [RelativeSource MarkupExtension documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx), it will tell you everything there is to know about `AncestorType` and `AncestorLevel`...