# How to get property from the DataTemplate's parent ViewModel class

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, parent

I am using MVVVM Light, so I set the DataContext of the Page to the Locator. Then I set the Pivot's ItemSource to a collection property inside "myFirstVM" ViewModel class. But how to set the text of the header of the PivotItem which is in a dataTemplate of TextBox to "MyProperty" which is also defined in "myFirstVM" class?

I look at this example, but cannot figure it out:
[How to access Parent's DataContext in Window 8 store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366609/how-to-access-parents-datacontext-in-window-8-store-apps/15419382#15419382)

**Here is my code:**

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:myApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:myApp.ViewModel"
x:Class="myApp.MyTripsPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Pivot Name="myPivot"
           Tag="{Binding}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding myFirstVM.DataSource}"
           ItemTemplate="{Binding myFirstVM.ViewDataTemplate}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, ElementName=myPivot}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `ElementName` in a binding will bind to the element itself (`Pivot` in this case), whereas you want to bind to something in the `DataContext` of `Pivot`, so just add DataContext to your path:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.myFirstVM.MyProperty, ElementName=myPivot}"/>
```