# Change DataTemplate style on the fly via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a parent `DataTemplate` with two child `DataTemplate` and want to change the property of just *one* of the child template's subcomponent (e.g. `Label.Foreground`, `TextBox.Background`, etc) based on a trigger. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127933/wpf-databinding-how-do-i-access-the-parent-data-context) which suggests a `RelativeSource` binding, but after many attempts I cannot get it to work and I'm not sure how to affect only one of the child templates. Below shows my expected end result (any/all of the right child properties need to be changed to show they're different from the left child).

[image]

The parent `DataTemplate` xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CoupleDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Left}"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"
                        />
        <Separator Grid.Column="1"
                       Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Right}"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        />

            <!-- Does not work, but shows what I'm trying to do. -->
            <!--<ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=ListBox},
                            Path=DataContext.IsFirstDifferent}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>-->

        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `CoupleDataTemplate` is then used in a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Couples}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CoupleDataTemplate}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The `Couples` property is

```
public ObservableCollection<Couple> Couples { get; private set; }
```

I've tried all sorts of different trigger binding to no avail. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, what am I missing?

#### The PersonDataTemplate per request

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Name="FirstLabel"
               Content="First:"
               />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Name="FirstTextBox"
                 Text="{Binding First}"
                 />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Name="LastLabel"
               Content="Last:"
               />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Name="LastTextBox"
                 Text="{Binding Last}"
                 />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Name="SexLabel"
               Content="Sex:"
               />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Name="Sex"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SexTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Sex}"
                  />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Add source of PersonDataTemplate, and of which type is {Binding Couples}? If it's IList<CoupleViewModel>, it doesn't make sense to bind against DataContext.IsFirstDifferent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone had given an answer but removed it for some reason. It gave me the idea of binding to the `Foreground` property. They had suggested using the `ContentControl.Tag` property in the `CoupleDataTemplate`, but that didn't really work for more than one subcomponent property.

The solution that evolved from the removed answer was to use a relative binding to the `DataContext.IsFirstDifferent` property and use a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert the `bool` to a color. So, for each `Label` in the `PersonDataTemplate` I create a custom relative binding. For example:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
       Name="FirstLabel"
       Content="First:"
       Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsFirstDifferent,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
            Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
            Converter={StaticResource IsDifferentConverter}}"
       />
```

Where the `IsDifferentConverter` source is:

```
public class DifferenceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Boolean)value) ? "Red" : "Black";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```