# WPF DataContext issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I've a WPF application, with which I use Prism for the architecture.

I've something a little bit custom:
I've one UserControl(a wizard), that can receive a `FrameworkElement`. This element is displayed within the wizard usercontrol with a `ContentPresenter`.

Basically, the view that will use this usercontrol will have such code:

```
<UserControl x:Class"My.Instance" 
  //skipping namespaces
  mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Wizard>
        <Wizard.ContentElement>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyInstanceProperty}"/>
        </Wizard.ContentElement>
    </Wizard>
</UserControl>
```

Within the "Wizard" UserControl, I just have such thing:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentElement}" Margin="10"/>
```

The context being the code behind of the usercontrol(set on the root `Grid`).

On runtime, I've the following error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :  BindingExpression path error:
>   'MyInstanceProperty' property not found on 'object' ''Wizard'
>   (HashCode=29548405)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyInstanceProperty;
>   DataItem='WizardViewModel' (HashCode=29548405); target element is
>   'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

So it seems that my TextBlock has its DataContext set on the Wizard UserControl, but not on the "My.Instance" owner.

I guess, it's because I host it within a ContentPresenter?

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127964/5147720

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MyInstanceProperty}"/>
```

EDIT>>>>>

Wizard view:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentElement}" Margin="10"/>
```

Wizard view model:

```
ContentElement = new pageViewModel();
```

App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModel:pageViewModel}">
    <local:pageView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I also found this previously, but can you explain me why my userControl is "loosing" his DataContext? (should not we use the ancestor type `My.Instance`?

Comment: Also, in my real case, I've several items given to the `Wizard`, only the "current/active" element is hosted inside a `ContentControl`, the other are just contained in a DependencyProperty. When I change the element(=move to the next step of the wizard), I've some binding error, so I've the feeling that this FindAncestor only work when the Control is hosted inside the ContentControl?

Comment: I've never used that "wizard" and I cant help you with that. When I want to create a view from my viewmodel without breaking the MVVM I always use that: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/

Comment: `Wizard`is a UserControl that I'm currently doing. The issue that I've is that I've a list of "Pages" in my `Wizard` and when I do next, I take the current page +1, and I display it. But when I do this I go an error with the RelativeSource+FindAncestor

Comment: So, your wizard is the main class. Maybe this be easier. Wizard view: <ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentElement}" Margin="10"/>. Wizard viewmodel: ContentElement = new otherUserControlViewModel(); And do the link in App.xaml. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I cannot do this, I've several FrameworkElement that are bound to the same ViewModel(since most of the pages needs data coming from the other pages), I need to be able to indicate the page X has now to be displayed. And more important, this ViewModel is unknown from the Wizard(the Wizard is generic, it only knows that it has to display some pages, and that each pages can be moved to next or previous). I've several usage of this wizard with totally different context(viewmodel+control)

Comment: Also, I've prism, everything is within modules, so I cannot have things that are so specific within the app.xaml