# WPF ListBox items command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I got following listbox

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <self:NewUserViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<ListBox x:Name="PermissionLbox"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListFromDataContext}" Height="75" Margin="10,117,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Why if I change CheckBox definition to:

```
<CheckBox Command={Binding CommandFromDataContext} Content="{Binding .}"></CheckBox><CheckBox   Content="{Binding .}"></CheckBox>
```

name CommandFromDataContex cannot be resolved although CommandFromDataContext exists in NewUserViewModel. The ListFromDataContext is a property of NewUserViewModel, Command either, but Command is not resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datacontext of the checkbox isnt the viewmodel any more, but rather the individual item it instances in the listbox.

You need to bind to a RelativeSource and Path to get to the ViewModel again.

See [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127933/wpf-databinding-how-do-i-access-the-parent-data-context) for details.

Comment: I've appended a link. See top voted answer for example.