# WPF How to bind to ICommand in the ViewModel from inside a ListView GridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a WPF application using MVVM. I have a view with a View Model as its DataContext.  Inside the View, I have a ListView binding to an observable collection.  On each row of the ListView, I have a button that I want to bind to an ICommand in the DataContext.  How do I set the RelativeSource to get to the DataContext ICommand?

**xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Frequency" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Frequency}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Enable State" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EnableState}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding RemoveTimerClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                           <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Delete.png" Width="20"/>
                       </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This Command binding is looking for a the ICommand in the Services.  I tried

```
Command="{Binding RemoveTimerClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

But this didn't work because it is binding to the UserControl (which is the View), not the DataContext (which is the View model).  How do I bind to the DataContext that also contains the Services collection?

Comment: How exactly this "does not work"? What error do you see (compile time error, runtime exception, binding error in the corresponding panel in the runtime, etc)?

Comment: This didn't work because it is binding to the UserControl (which is the View), not the DataContext (which is the View model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1127964/5032172). You have to add `DataContext` to the bound command:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveTimerClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```